# operator illegal for class in template function

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ templates and I have a function for different types of maps:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T m1, T m2){ //map m1 and map m2
    map<pair<T, int>, int>::iterator itr1 = m1.begin();
    map<pair<T, int>, int>::iterator itr2 = m2.begin();

    while (itr1 != m1.end() && itr2 != m2.end()){
        //do something with itr1 and itr2
    }
}
```

When I compile it in VS2013, I got the error: `error C2088: '!=' : illegal for class` which points to `while (itr1 != m1.end() && itr2 != m2.end())`. But if I explicitly declare the type of the maps (i.e. don't use template), I don't have the error. Could anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map<pair<T, int>, int>::iterator` is an iterator from a map which key type is `pair<T, int>` (where `T` is apparently also a `map` in your example) and which value type is `int`, which is clearly different from `typename T::iterator` which is the type of `m1.begin()`. What you probably want is:

```
template<typename T> 
void foo(T m1, T m2) {
    typename T::iterator itr1 = m1.begin();
    /* ... */
}
```

Or:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(std::map<std::pair<T, int>, int> m1, 
         std::map<std::pair<T, int>, int> m2) {
    typename T::iterator itr1 = m1.begin();
    /* ... */
}
```

In the first case, the template parameter is the type of the `map` (`T = std::map<std::pair<T, int>>`) while in the second case it is the type of the first attribute of the key of the map.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I've messed the template parameters. It works now. Thanks!